# C Set Array size by strlen()

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char, string-length

In C, not C++,  I tried to set a char array size using a strlen() contained in a const int.

```
char *input = "hello";

//now the integer that contains the lenght
static const int lengthA = strlen(input); //upto here, it works

char list_array[lengthA]; //here doesn't work, because the variable lengthA is not initialized
```

So, I want that the length of **input** is used as the length of the **array**.

I already tried with **sizeof**, instead of **strlen**, but it returns the byte

Is this possible?

Comment: If your compiler supports variable length arrays then the presented code is valid provided that the keyword static will be removed for the constant lengthA.

Comment: What exactly happens with this code?  What error messages do you get, if any?  Also, what compiler are you using?  Is it by chance MSVC?

Comment: I'm using VS, the error is "error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant". But microsoft site doesn't help me.

Comment: Keep in mind that an array of `strlen("hello")` characters is not big enough to hold the string `"hello"`. If you want to store the string `"hello"` in `list_array`, you need to allocate one more byte for the `'\0'` terminator. (You can store the characters `'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'` in 5 bytes, but then the contents of `list_array` won't be a string, and any string operation applied to it will be undefined.)

Comment: please edit your question to include the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you're using is called a **variable length array**, where the size of an array is determined at runtime.  However, Visual Studio does not support this feature.

You'll need to allocate memory dynamically with `malloc`:

```
char *input = "hello";
static const int lengthA = strlen(input);
char *list_array = malloc(lengthA);
```

Comment: Variable length arrays are nonexistent in C90, required in C99, and optional in C11. Microsoft has recently announced C11 support for Visual Studio, but they don't plan to support VLAs. Feel free to add this to your answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use correct types. `strlen` returns `size_t` not `int`
2. You can only initialize static and global variables with constant expressions. You cant use any function calls or variables to initialize them.
3. You can use to non-constant expressions to initialize and define automatic variables.

```
char *input = "hello";
char input1[] = "hello";

static const size_t lengthA = sizeof(input1); 

char list_array[sizeof(input1)];


void foo(void)
{
    const size_t lengthA = strlen(input); 
    char listArray[lengthA + 1];  
}
```

node the `+1` in the definition of local variable. You need it to accomodate the string and also the terminating null character

Answer (score -1):

Please try this.

```
char *list_array = calloc(lengthA, sizeof(char));
```

Comment: it will also do not work for the static storage variables.